# extracting column names from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file with 100's of columns in it. Currently im able to read the csv file and its particular row. My file is inside a zipfile and here is the code i have so far.

```
import os, sys, csv, zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('some_zip_file.zip')
f = zip_file.open('some_csv_file.csv', 'r')

for row in csv.reader(f):
    print row[1]

f.close()
```

But is there a way to extract only the column names from the csv file? Im using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next(csv.reader(f))` will return just the first row (which is presumably where the column names are.)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the first line of the file, by your code:

```
import os, sys, csv, zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('some_zip_file.zip')
f = zip_file.open('some_csv_file.csv', 'r')

for column in csv.reader(f).next():
    print column
    # collumn_name
```

Hope that helps.